# Javascript extension to use C based APIs(clutter) in a webapp

Tags: javascript, webkit, dom-events, swig, clutter

**My goal is to use the C libraries to form web apps.**

I have chosen the way to do that via using "SWIG" tool.
The Swig tool requires three things:

1. `.c` file which defines all the functions.
2. `.i` file also called interface file which is creating the
   interface to load the APIs wherein I used the `extern` keyword.
3. APP written in Javascript extension (`.js` file).

I used SWIG tool to compile and run this app to verify the `.js` file has made correctly.
The application is running fine on XMING X11 window.

On compilation it creates `_wrap.o`, `.o` file and `libFILENAME.so`.

Now I want to run this *app* on browser page.

For this I have used the webkit clutter port which gives us the MxLauncher code.
I'm using `webkit_iweb_view_load_uri(WEBKIT_IWEB_VIEW(view), "filename.html");` API to load my html file to run that Javascript on my webpage view.

I'm linking the `.so` created at the compilation time.

> *Error Message*: JS CONSOLE: file:///filename.js:
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: example

**filename.c**

```
int gcd(int x, int y) `enter code here`{
  int g;
  g = y;
  while (x > 0) {
    g = x;
    x = y % x;
    y = g;
  }
  return g;
}
```

**filename.i**

```
%module example
extern int    gcd(int x, int y);
```

**filename.js**

```
x = 42;
y = 105;
g = example.gcd(x,y);
```

How to get my goal to be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

You also need to tell WebKit/JavaScriptCore at runtime about your bindings (this is in addition to linking with filename_wrap.o).

Specifically you need to bind them to the global JavaScript object (in order to invoke per your .js examples).  A callback on the WebKit window can be used to get a timely reference to the global JavaScript context, and then you can register your functions onto it.

Adapting this [example](https://github.com/vrruiz/WebKit-JavaScriptCore-Extensions/blob/master/webkit-02.c#L87) of hooking into the `window-object-cleared` signal the code could look similar to this:

```
/* the window callback - 
     fired when the JavaScript window object has been cleared */
static void window_object_cleared_cb(WebKitWebView  *web_view,
                                     WebKitWebFrame *frame,
                                     gpointer        context,
                                     gpointer        window_object,
                                     gpointer        user_data)
{
  /* Add your classes to JavaScriptCore */
  example_init(context); // example_init generated by SWIG
}


/* ... and in your main application set up */
void yourmainfunc()
{
    ....

    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (web_view), "window-object-cleared",
        G_CALLBACK(window_object_cleared_cb), web_view);

    webkit_web_view_load_uri (WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW (web_view), "file://filename.html");

    ...
}
```

Depending on which branch of SWIG you are using you may need to generate the `example_init` function yourself (check filename.cxx); for reference here is what an initializer function to [register wrapped C functions](https://github.com/oliver----/swig-v8/blob/devel/Doc/Manual/Javascript.md#wrapper-functions) would look like in SWIG:

```
int example_init(JSContextRef context) {
  JSObjectRef global = JSContextGetGlobalObject(context);
 ...
  jsc_registerFunction(context, global,  "gcd", _wrap_gcd);
 ...
}
```

*NOTE -- SWIG does not yet officially support JavaScript; the above refers to using the work-in-progress (non-production) SWIG branches.*

References:

- SWIG-V8 [source](https://github.com/oliver----/swig-v8) and its [Javascript documentation](https://github.com/oliver----/swig-v8/blob/devel/Doc/Manual/Javascript.md#wrapper-functions)
- swig-jsc [source](https://github.com/ashishs99/swig-jsc) and its [example](https://github.com/ashishs99/swig-jsc/blob/a15943ac/Examples/javascript/simple/runme.cxx#L95) of registering bindings
- SWIG JavaScriptCore GSoC project [source](https://github.com/Neha03/gsoc2012-javascript) (Google Summer of Code 2012)
- Webkit: Extending JavaScript article-- [tutorial](http://rvr.typepad.com/wind/2011/10/webkit-extending-javascript-1.html) /  [example code](https://github.com/vrruiz/WebKit-JavaScriptCore-Extensions)