# How to call a JavaScript function from C using JavaScriptCore?

Tags: javascript, c, function, swig, javascriptcore

I've written a function in JavaScript. For example:

```js
function myName(a)
{
   var k=10;
   print(k);
}
```

Is it possible to call `myName` from C using JavaScriptCore? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the Google's V8 project (It's written in C++, though). Which allows you to compile and execute a javascript program within a C++ program (with the help of the embeded v8 engine). Here is its [Getting Started document page](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started)

Comment: Basically I'm accessing my all the c functions in javascript by using the SWIG Tool(It creates wrapper functions corresponding to all API's used). You can refer link for more description about my goal.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681780/javascript-extension-to-use-c-based-apisclutter-in-a-webapp
All my API's has been working fine after exposing it.
One single API "g_signal_connect" [http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect] I'm not able to expose. Please assist If you have any idea about calling this.

Comment: My Wrapper function is like this:

ulong JS_g_signal_connect(ClutterActor* actor,const char* eventName, char* calledFunction,  gpointer data){
return g_signal_connect(actor, eventName, GCallback(calledFunction), data);
}

My function "calledFunction" is defined in javascript. I'm calling my wrapper function from javascript language. with the syntax


example.JS_g_signal_connect(actor, "button-press-event,"functionName", NULL);

Comment: I'm not familiar with SWIG, but it seems quite interesting. I'll take a look at my spare time. I'll leave a post if I can do someting :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. One way to do it is, from C, call JSEvaluateScript. Something like this:

```
JSStringRef script = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("myName()");
JSEvaluateScript(ctx, script, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

This assumes you've created ctx (a JSContextRef) using JSGlobalContextCreate and have already evaluated your script in that context (again using JSEvaluateScript) to add the myName function to that ctx.